# How to connect/enable VMware to use GPS from windows?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, windows-11, gps, gpsd

I have a GPS module built into my laptop, the problem is that it's not being enabled on the VM.
How can I change this?

I have verified that on the windows side it works fine, I am trying to use it with navit and running `cgps -s` shows results as N/A, do I have to buy a separate GPS module, or can I enable my integrated one?

> Host: Windows 11 64-Bit, VMWare Workstation 16 Player

> VM: ubuntu 20.04 minimal, openbox+xorg 64-bit (USB auto connect + USB 2.0 support enabled)

Comment: Look in VMware menu, Removable Devices, and see if the GSM module can be added. I have not done this particular one myself, but I have done other removable devices.

Comment: Is it a removable device? What does it look like in Device Manager?

Comment: Even if GPS is built-in in your laptop there is a chance that it is connected using a bus like USB or serial which can be forwarded into the VM. Check Windows device manager, select your GPS and then switch view to Devices by connection. Then you may be able to see how GPS is connected to your system.

Comment: @Robert it is connected via USB bus/that's what it's popped up as, but VMware is not recognizing it, Is there a way I can forward it to VMware. If it's simpler is there a way to use a mock location, or IP location instead of GPS, as the test device (Raspberry PI) will arrive in a week or so, with an external module, which will hopefully work, I just need to see if navit works so I can continue making my project. Thanks in advance!